# Eclipse photon Error when executing code in Debug Shell

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse photon, and I want to executing code while debugging, therefore, I'm using Debug Shell (Display in previous versions of eclipse), however I get the following error :

> To perform an evaluation, an expression must be compiled in the context of a Java project's build path. The current execution context is not associated with a Java project in the workspace.
>       Evaluation failed. Reason(s): Unable to evaluate the selected expression:
>           To perform an evaluation, an expression must be compiled in the context of a Java project's build path. The current execution context is not associated with a Java project in the workspace.

**Edit**

here is a screenshot :[image]

I also have problem with the Expressions view, it doesn't update variable's state when I added them 

**Edit2 **

here is two screens of what happens when I select a running Thread vs when I select a paused thread :

- running thread : [image]
- paused thread : [image]

Comment: Make sure a paused thread is selected in the _Debug_ view. Please add a screenshot that shows both, the _Debug_ and the _Debug Shell_ view to your question.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried your proposition but I'm getting the same error message.

Comment: I guess it is because the selected thread is suspended instead of is paused at a breakpoint. Therefore the context cannot be used to execute your code in the _Debug Shell_ view (the execution of the synchronized code block must be finished first).

Comment: In fact, it is paused at a breakpoint,

Comment: The thread has the suffix _(Suspended)_ and the icon of the topmost stack trace item is decorated with a clock which means synchronized. Maybe the thread is waiting for something that is blocked by the paused by breakpoint thread. Does double-click on the topmost stack trace item navigates you to the line with the breakpoint?

Comment: I verified that the thread was suspended due to breakpoint, and yeah double-click on the topmost stack trace item navigates me to the line with the breakpoint .( however I remarked that the breakpoint icon doesn't appears on the left of the line (as always), but it appears in the Breakpoints view )

Comment: Are all threads paused? Is there another paused thread that is not suffixed with _"(Suspended)"_? If yes, does it work if you select this thread?

Comment: I think that you are right, there a relationship between the selected thread and the execution of code in the debug shell, I remarked that when I select the paused thread I can execute code (but I get the error ), however, when I select a running thread I cannot run the code !!

Comment: Yes, a paused and non-suspended thread must be selected. Or to be even more precise, the context in the _Debug Shell_ refers to the selected stack element. For example, if a method calls a method, only the variables before the breakpoint or the method call are visible and by selecting the stack element you choose only the context given by one of the two methods. If a thread was stopped by a breakpoint, another thread may also be stopped, e. g. when the thread stopped by the breakpoint holds a lock that is also required by the other suspended thread.